# VPN keeps my internet access running in Ubuntu 22.04 and stops when i disconnect from VPN

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn

I am using proton VPN and due to the ongoing issue, I have ran this in terminal

'''sudo service network-manager restart '''

but after that my VPN connection stops responding and a popup message displays with

***authentication required***

I tried giving my Ubuntu password and also proton VPN password, nothing works.

Then I ran
'''sudo systemctl restart Network Manager'''
and
'''sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches'''
but the problem still remains the same.

I have no clue why is this happening.